# How to avoid multiple cache clearing for one edited record?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

We have the problem:
An editor edits a news record, which contains 8 images. The installation is configured to clear cache of 4 pages if a news record is edited. (`TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd = 12,13,14,15`)
But instead of one clearance of cache for those 4 pages, each clearance occurs 9 times: one for the news record, and one for each (unchanged) referenced file. These multiple cache clearings take very much time and it even occurs that an error is thrown.

How can we avoid the multiple clearing of the cache for the same pages?
Can we speed up the cache clearance with additional indexes?
Can we use hooks to clear those page caches just one time?

Comment: Do you clear the cache via TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd = cacheTag:tx_news, or else?

Comment: I added the clear cache config in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Its a known bug [1], that TYPO3 clears cache tags one after another and that this affects performance.
That bug applies to your case, as TYPO3 will eventually flush 4 tags (`pageId_12`, `pageId_13`, `pageId_14` and `pageId_15`) [2].

There is a not-yet-reviewed patch [3] for TYPO3 7.6 which you could try to backport to TYPO3 6.2.

Site note: Of course it's better to use `TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd = cacheTag:tx_news`, if that's applicable in your case (i.e that you didn't want to clear only a subset of pages that contain the news plugin.

[1] https://forge.typo3.org/issues/78596

[2] https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_6-2/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#L7344

[3] https://review.typo3.org/#/c/50785/